# Question about open and closed sets in a relative metric space.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

So I have that $A= [0,1]$, $B=(\frac{1}{2},1]$, and  $C=(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4})$.

The relative metric is defined as $d'(x,y) =|x-y|$ where $x,y$ are in $[0,1]$.

The definition of being open in a relative metric space is that the a set $Y$ is open in $X$ iff $Y=X$ intersect $U$, where $U$ is open in $M$.

My question is, is $B$ open in $A$?
I mean their intersection is $(\frac{1}{2},1]$.

What would $U$ be considered here?

Comment: What is your $M$ here?

Comment: Yes, $B$ is open in $A$ since $B=A\cap(1/2,\infty),$ where $(1/2,\infty)$ is open in $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

$U$ could be any open set containing $(1/2, 1]$. So $U$ could be, say, $(1/2, 2)$ which is open in $\mathbb R$. So $B = U \cap A$ so $B$ is open in $A$.

The point is an open set is that for every point $x$ (even the 1) of there is an $\epsilon$ where all $y$ in $A$ that $|y - x| < \epsilon$. This is true for the point $1$ as there are no points larger than $1$ in $A$.

Since every point of $U$ has an open neighborhood entirely in $U$ then in $A = M \cap U$ every point will have an open neighborhood intersect $U$ entirely in $A$.

Comment: With that respect, then B would not be closed since the intersection would not contain 1/2 correct?